# How to get query command on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, batch, query, users

I have a Windows 10 computer on which I need to see what users are logged in via an SSH connection (which is the command prompt). I figured I could run `query user` on the machine, but the `query` command is not installed. Where can I get it? To clarify, this is a Windows Command prompt command that comes installed on most windows servers. **I dont have query.exe and want to get it on my computer...**

Comment: What do you mean by 'Query Command' is not installed. Are you talking about command prompt?

Comment: Command prompt and powershell yes. Hence "command" and my "batch" tag.

Comment: I don't understand. When you press Start+R (Run) then type CMD. What comes up?

Comment: Hey Mark— From an admin elevated command prompt, run `sfc /scannnow`, reboot, and then try it again. Let us know the results afterwards.

Comment: I'm talking about the command `query` in the command prompt. Like the command `echo` or `dir`. The *actual command you would run to query user data*

Comment: Did you try `sfc /scannnow` from admin elevated command prompt yet?

Comment: No because it doesnt come with my version of windows, and I was wondering if there is a way to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 Home does not include `query.exe`. `query.exe` is part of Windows Remote Desktop Services (previously called Windows Terminal Services). While the core of Remote Desktop is present in Windows 10 Home, and indeed is used to implement fast user switching and Remote Assistance (now called "Quick Assist"), various features of it have been disabled, including the removal of the command line utilities such as `query.exe`. By contrast, higher Windows 10 editions including Pro do include those command line utilities.

However, since the underlying APIs are still present, the command line utilities do actually work on Windows 10 Home if you copy them from a Windows 10 Pro (or higher) machine.

I have two machines, one runs Windows 10 Pro and the other runs Windows 10 Home. Both running build 2004. I can successfully get `query.exe` to work on the Windows 10 Home machine by copying these four files from Windows 10 Pro:

- `C:\Windows\System32\query.exe`
- `C:\Windows\System32\Query.dll`
- `C:\Windows\System32\en-US\Query.dll.mui`
- `C:\Windows\System32\en-US\query.exe.mui`

You don't need to put them in `C:\Windows\System32` on the Win10 Home machine. It is sufficient to put those the `query.exe` and `query.dll` files in any directory, and then put the two `.mui` files in a `en-US` subdirectory of that directory. (Note that the `.mui` file path is correct for US English Windows, if you are using another language those files will come from another subdirectory than `en-US`.)

After doing the above, running `query.exe` fails with this error: `Can't load QUERY commands from the registry (error 1).`

To fix that, we need to do the following: `reg export "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Utilities\query" query.reg` on the Pro machine, and then `reg import query.reg` on the Home machine. Now, `query.exe` works.

But all `query user` does is call `quser.exe`, so `query user` is not going to work on Win10 Home because you don't have `quser.exe` – you can try copying that as well. Actually all `query.exe` does is delegate to a bunch of other executables: `quser.exe`, `qappsrv.exe`, `qprocess.exe`, `qwinsta.exe`. For `query.exe` to work, you need those EXEs, none of which are included in Win10 Home. You might as well just skip `query.exe` and copy whichever underlying EXEs you actually need.

For example, if you copy `C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\en-US\quser.exe.mui` to Win10 Home, `quser.exe` works. You just have to make sure `quser.exe.mui` is in an `en-US` subdirectory of the directory containing `quser.exe`. I haven't tried any of the other `q` commands, but the others can likely be made to work using the same approach.

(Note while this technically works, I don't know whether it complies with Microsoft's licensing agreements. If you are concerned about that topic, do this at your own risk.)

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem using a Win10Home.
I copied quser.exe from an Win10Pro machine. It works on my Win10Home too!

Answer (score 2):

`%windir%\system32\query.exe` is **not available** in Windows 10 Home.

**Windows 10 Pro** does have it. I just ran a search in my PCs.

Answer (score -1):

You actually have to open `cmd.exe` and run `query user` - if you run it by itself from your run bar it will immediately exit.

If you are literally missing the `query.exe` and `query.dll` from your `%windir%\system32` folder you can try finding it elsewhere on your computer (mine also has it in a subfolder of `%windir%\WinSxS`, for instance), otherwise you should be able to copy those files from a different computer with the same environment.

Comment: Right. I know how commands work. The command is not found.

Comment: Just making sure you were actually running it from a `cmd.exe` window and not via run since it would just exit before displaying anything. I recommend going to your `%windir%\system32` folder and making sure `query.exe` is actually there. If it is, you may need to check your environment variables and make sure your Path location is correct on your system; if it's not there is likely a repair/reset needed.

Comment: Of course running it from run wouldn't do anything. And no, query.exe is not there, that is my point. I'm wondering where to get the executable for my computer!