# How to find out when I logged in to my current Windows session?

Tags: windows, uptime

I want to know at which hour I logged in to my current session, I don't think `uptime` in Task Manager is what I'm looking for, because based on my understanding `uptime` is not the same as current user logged in time.

Is there any PowerShell command I can use in Windows to determine how long I have been logged in to the current session?

[image: Task manager screenshot]

Above is the image of my task manger, how can up time be 7 days? I dont understand.

Comment: You're correct, system uptime is an entirely different kettle of ghoti from user logged-in time. For a thorough explanation of Task Manager Up Time, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1622932/330527) on similar question.

Comment: ... and searching for something entirely unrelated this popped up on the side panel of a site :-D https://winbuzzer.com/2021/03/12/how-to-check-uptime-on-windows-10-with-task-manager-powershell-or-command-prompt-xcxwbt

Comment: 'uptime' is essentially a unix construct. It doesn't care how much you've been active at the computer, or how much time it slept. It simply measures 'time since last reboot'.

Comment: Are you trying to find out how long since the PC has been turned on or how long since the user logged in? Those are two different questions in your title and body, it's confusing.

Comment: I usually look in the security log for entries ID: 4624 where the Login Type is 2 . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624

Answer (score 5):

### query

**Note:** `query.exe` requires Windows 10 Pro and higher, and does not exist on Windows 10 Home. See this question for more information: [How to get query command on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1440493/how-to-get-query-command-on-windows-10)

You can run the command [`query user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user) to find how long your user session has been logged in for. There is also a shorter [`quser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/quser) (thanks @Destroy666!). Works in both CMD or PowerShell.

Use `LOGON TIME` to find out when you logged in and calculate from there.

[image: PowerShell screenshot]

### net

You can also run the `net stats workstation` command. It will show you `Statistics since ...` the time you logged in.

[image: CMD screenshot]

Comment: This also works as shorter `quser` and it doesn't require  PowerShell as it's just an executable located in `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: Good to know, thanks! PowerShell is in the example since OP mentioned they wanted to use PowerShell, but yes it's not required.

Comment: `quser` is not present in all the versions of windows it not in home version

Comment: @Yanjan.Kaf. I see, yeah `query` is only available in Windows 10 Pro and higher. Does Windows 10 Home have access to the `net` command? You can try `net stats workstation`